# List of female chess players by peak FIDE rating

Tags: history, rating, fide, statistics, records

**Update**: The answer currently doesn't include countries and other trivia like in the original one. Please consider posting an answer with at least the countries or editing current answer to include these. I actually did include countries in my example with Judit Polgar, so I'll consider the current answer incomplete...unless we get an answer here: [List of female chess players by peak FIDE rating with countries?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36698/list-of-female-chess-players-by-peak-fide-rating-with-countries)

---

There is a [Wiki list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_players_by_peak_FIDE_rating) is for all of the top-rated FIDE chess players. But where is the list of top female chess players by peak FIDE rating?

I'll start:

1 - Hungary - Judit Polgar - 2735 - 2005-07 -   1976 - N/A - first and only female player so far to achieve 2700+ rating

Comment: Top 17 appears here: https://2700chess.com/women

Comment: @David: Those are unofficial live ratings. The list at Wikipedia that was to be modelled is for the official monthly FIDE ratings.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The raw data which could be used to extract this information is available on the FIDE website ([from 2001](https://ratings.fide.com/download.phtml)) and the Olimpbase website ([before 2001](https://www.olimpbase.org/Elo/data/elo1967-2001.zip)). What you will need to do is clean the data (the older the data the more "dirty" it is), construct a relational database and insert the data. Then you will be able to use SQL to search the database for the data you want.

Having done this, here is a list of the top female players of all time above 2500 appearing in the periodic FIDE rating lists (i.e. not the live list, because that data is not available to us):

**FullName**    **Max** **Period**

1. Polgar, Judit 2735 7/2005, 10/2005
2. Hou, Yifan 2686 3/2015, 5/2015
3. Koneru, Humpy 2623 7/2009
4. Muzychuk, Anna 2606 7/2012, 8/2012
5. Ju, Wenjun 2604 3/2017
6. Goryachkina, Aleksandra 2593 2/2021
7. Kosintseva, Tatiana 2581 11/2020
8. Zhao, Xue 2579 9/2013, 10/2013
9. Polgar, Zsuzsa 2577 1/2005 ->
10. Kosintseva, Nadezhda 2576 11/2010
11. Xie, Jun 2574 1/2008 ->
12. Dzagnidze, Nana 2573 6/2015 - 10/2015
13. Muzychuk, Mariya 2563 3/2016, 4-6/2019
14. Kosteniuk, Alexandra 2561 1/2018, 2/2018
15. Lahno, Kateryna 2560 12/2018 - 2/2019
16. Galliamova, Alisa 2560 7/1998
17. Stefanova, Antoaneta 2560 1/2003, 5-7/2010
18. Chiburdanidze, Maia 2560 1/1988
19. Cramling, Pia 2550 10/2008
20. Gunina, Valentina 2548 6-7/2015
21. Zhu, Chen 2548 1/2008
22. Lei, Tingjie 2545 3/2018
23. Harika, Dronavalli 2543 11-12/2016
24. Cmilyte, Viktorija 2542 6/2017
25. Sebag, Marie 2537 3/2013
26. Zatonskih, Anna 2537 5/2011
27. Khotenashvili, Bela 2531 6/2013
28. Tan, Zhongyi 2530 3-4/2016
29. Batsiashvili, Nino 2528 3/2018
30. Danielian, Elina 2521 7/2011
31. Ioseliani, Nana 2520 7/1997
32. Saduakassova, Dinara 2519 1/2020
33. Xu, Yuhua 2517 4/2006 - 7/2007
34. Paehtz, Elisabeth 2513 9-10/2018
35. Wang, Lei 2512 10/2001
36. Hoang, Thanh Trang 2511 11/2013 - 2/2014
37. Pogonina, Natalija 2508 7/2014
38. Kovalevskaya, Ekaterina 2507 7/2001
39. Zhu, Jiner 2507 10/2019
40. Arakhamia-Grant, Ketevan 2506 7/2009
41. Wang, Pin 2506 10/2000
42. Polgar, Sofia 2505 7/1998
43. Girya, Olga 2505 9/2017
44. Socko, Monika 2505 4/2008
45. Ruan, Lufei 2503 1/2014
46. Mkrtchian, Lilit 2503 1-3/2010
47. Matveeva, Svetlana 2502 1/2004
48. Krush, Irina 2502 10-11/2013
49. Ushenina, Anna 2502 7/2007
50. Qin, Kanying 2501 7/2000
51. Skripchenko, Almira 2501 1-4/2003

Comment: Are you sure about Skripchenko, Almira 2501 1-4/2003 ? It says on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almira_Skripchenko) 'Peak rating 2498 (January 2002)' maybe not updated?

Comment: @BCLC: That was an error on Wikipedia; I fixed it there. See https://ratings.fide.com/toparc.phtml?cod=42 and https://ratings.fide.com/toparc.phtml?cod=46.

Answer (score 0):

There's now [a corresponding section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_players_by_peak_FIDE_rating#Highest-rated_female_players) in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_players_by_peak_FIDE_rating), which is currently up to date.