# List of chess players by their peak FIDE blitz rating

Tags: rating, fide, statistics, blitz

I've come across a list of the highest FIDE ratings ever achieved by all 2700+ players in the 2700chess.com:

[image]

This shows all the players above 2700 in classical ordered by their FIDE peak rating. It also shows when and where the respective peak rating was acquired. (This can also be found on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_players_by_peak_FIDE_rating).)

I tried to find a similar list for the FIDE blitz ratings but to no success.

**Is there a place that has a list of the highest official FIDE blitz ratings by player ? If not, then may you please provide a list similar to [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34754/list-of-female-chess-players-by-peak-fide-rating)? (Please include their [countries](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36698/list-of-female-chess-players-by-peak-fide-rating-with-countries).)**

It can be either for the top 100, or all players above 2700. Any of those lists would be good.

Curiously when i hover in the current live top 100 blitz ratings in 2700chess.com i can see the player's peak:

[image]

But it doesn't seem have a list with the best blitz's only.

Comment: You can use the advanced search at http://ratings.fide.com to get players listed by blitz (or other) rating , but I don't see how to get a similar list using peak ratings.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a place that has a list of the highest official FIDE blitz ratings by player ?

Not as far as I know.

> If not, then may you please provide a list similar to here? (Please include their countries.)

Here are the results from the relevant queries on my database constructed from the downloads available from the [FIDE rating download website](https://ratings.fide.com/download.phtml) for players with blitz ratings of 2700 and over. Since you also ask for countries I've included distinct player/country combinations. So, So appears twice, once for the Philippines and once for the US. Similarly Caruana for both Italy and the US and winner in the appearances category, Firouza appears 3 times for Iran, FIDE and France.

The "Period" is the first FIDE rating list in which the player achieved the rating. If the player didn't play rated blitz for a year after that then they obviously retain the rating for the next year so the "Period" is the year and month in which FIDE first recorded that rating for them.

**PlayerName    FedName MaxRating   Period**

1. Carlsen, Magnus Norway 2986 2017/12
2. Vachier-Lagrave, Maxime France 2948 2019/07
3. Nakamura, Hikaru United States 2934 2019/03
4. Grischuk, Alexander Russia 2923 2012/08
5. Karjakin, Sergey Russia 2906 2013/01
6. Nepomniachtchi, Ian Russia 2880 2014/07
7. Andreikin, Dmitry Russia 2877 2012/08
8. Ding, Liren China 2875 2016/04
9. Aronian, Levon Armenia 2871 2018/07
10. Mamedyarov, Shakhriyar Azerbaijan 2866 2014/12
11. So, Wesley United States 2861 2021/07
12. Artemiev, Vladislav Russia 2849 2018/05
13. Le, Quang Liem Vietnam 2843 2013/08
14. Kramnik, Vladimir Russia 2841 2016/06
15. Anand, Viswanathan India 2832 2018/12
16. Shkuro, Iuri Ukraine 2828 2017/03
17. Giri, Anish Netherlands 2822 2016/05
18. Caruana, Fabiano United States 2818 2018/06
19. Duda, Jan-Krzysztof Poland 2818 2019/01
20. Bogdanovich, Stanislav Ukraine 2815 2015/05
21. Ivanchuk, Vassily Ukraine 2815 2017/12
22. Yu, Yangyi China 2812 2019/09
23. Morozevich, Alexander Russia 2811 2014/10
24. Firoozja, Alireza France 2810 2021/07
25. Mamedov, Rauf Azerbaijan 2810 2016/01
26. Radjabov, Teimour Azerbaijan 2808 2015/01
27. Navara, David Czech Republic 2806 2015/06
28. Svidler, Peter Russia 2805 2019/01
29. Dubov, Daniil Russia 2804 2017/01
30. Kasparov, Garry Russia 2801 2017/09
31. Fedoseev, Vladimir Russia 2798 2015/05
32. Korobov, Anton Ukraine 2797 2014/01
33. Ponomariov, Ruslan Ukraine 2797 2013/07
34. Adams, Michael England 2796 2019/01
35. Dominguez Perez, Leinier Cuba 2796 2017/01
36. Tomashevsky, Evgeny Russia 2793 2016/04
37. Gelfand, Boris Israel 2792 2016/04
38. Nguyen, Ngoc Truong Son Vietnam 2791 2013/07
39. Leko, Peter Hungary 2790 2017/04
40. Bortnik, Alexandr Ukraine 2784 2016/07
41. Wang, Hao China 2784 2016/04
42. Lu, Shanglei China 2781 2015/05
43. Rapport, Richard Hungary 2776 2021/07
44. Caruana, Fabiano Italy 2775 2012/07
45. Harikrishna, P. India 2774 2016/04
46. Kovalenko, Igor Latvia 2774 2015/03
47. Firoozja, Alireza FIDE 2770 2020/07
48. Bu, Xiangzhi China 2767 2019/06
49. Salem, A.R. Saleh United Arab Emirates 2767 2017/07
50. Andriasian, Zaven Armenia 2766 2018/04
51. Amonatov, Farrukh Tajikistan 2764 2016/07
52. Petrosian, Tigran L. Armenia 2762 2018/01
53. Matlakov, Maxim Russia 2760 2020/01
54. Bruzon Batista, Lazaro Cuba 2758 2012/07
55. Jobava, Baadur Georgia 2758 2017/01
56. Kamsky, Gata United States 2756 2012/09
57. Vidit, Santosh Gujrathi India 2756 2019/12
58. Zubov, Alexander Ukraine 2754 2019/08
59. Topalov, Veselin Bulgaria 2752 2012/07
60. Ghaem Maghami, Ehsan Iran 2751 2020/03
61. Kasimdzhanov, Rustam Uzbekistan 2750 2017/06
62. Dreev, Aleksey Russia 2749 2014/07
63. Sargissian, Gabriel Armenia 2749 2014/07
64. Sjugirov, Sanan Russia 2748 2018/11
65. Malakhov, Vladimir Russia 2747 2015/04
66. Bacrot, Etienne France 2744 2013/03
67. Riazantsev, Alexander Russia 2744 2013/10
68. So, Wesley Philippines 2744 2014/07
69. Dominguez Perez, Leinier United States 2743 2015/12
70. Onischuk, Vladimir Ukraine 2743 2015/08
71. Smirin, Ilia Israel 2743 2014/11
72. Wojtaszek, Radoslaw Poland 2743 2014/07
73. Wei, Yi China 2740 2017/06
74. Gretarsson, Hjorvar Steinn Iceland 2737 2017/11
75. Polgar, Judit Hungary 2736 2014/07
76. Maghsoodloo, Parham Iran 2735 2019/09
77. Jakovenko, Dmitry Russia 2734 2012/08
78. Jones, Gawain C B England 2734 2016/05
79. Savchenko, Boris Russia 2734 2015/05
80. Adly, Ahmed Egypt 2733 2016/10
81. Chadaev, Nikolai Russia 2733 2013/03
82. Iturrizaga, Eduardo Venezuela 2733 2016/10
83. Bologan, Viktor Moldova 2732 2012/07
84. Dlugy, Maxim United States 2731 2012/08
85. Shimanov, Aleksandr Russia 2731 2012/08
86. Movsesian, Sergei Armenia 2730 2013/07
87. Tkachiev, Vladislav France 2730 2014/01
88. Alekseev, Evgeny Russia 2729 2015/06
89. Bauer, Christian France 2728 2019/07
90. Inarkiev, Ernesto Russia 2728 2013/03
91. Fressinet, Laurent France 2727 2013/03
92. Melkumyan, Hrant Armenia 2727 2016/01
93. Vitiugov, Nikita Russia 2727 2015/11
94. Meier, Georg Germany 2726 2014/07
95. Georgiev, Kiril Bulgaria 2725 2013/03
96. Firoozja, Alireza Iran 2724 2019/01
97. Xiong, Jeffrey United States 2724 2019/11
98. Efimenko, Zahar Ukraine 2719 2012/10
99. Socko, Bartosz Poland 2718 2017/06
100. Bocharov, Ivan Russia 2715 2018/11
101. Shirov, Alexei Latvia 2715 2013/03
102. McShane, Luke J England 2713 2012/07
103. Kuzubov, Yuriy Ukraine 2712 2015/05
104. Laznicka, Viktor Czech Republic 2711 2015/11
105. Safarli, Eltaj Azerbaijan 2711 2017/05
106. Amin, Bassem Egypt 2709 2018/01
107. Bachmann, Axel Paraguay 2709 2016/04
108. Bruzon Batista, Lazaro United States 2709 2018/01
109. Kravtsiv, Martyn Ukraine 2709 2019/07
110. Guseinov, Gadir Azerbaijan 2708 2018/10
111. Moiseenko, Alexander Ukraine 2708 2012/07
112. Topalov, Veselin FIDE 2708 2017/12
113. Tsydypov, Zhamsaran Russia 2708 2019/03
114. Najer, Evgeniy Russia 2707 2013/10
115. Sasikiran, Krishnan India 2707 2012/07
116. Kononenko, Dmitry Ukraine 2706 2015/08
117. Ponkratov, Pavel Russia 2705 2016/08
118. Swiercz, Dariusz Poland 2705 2016/04
119. Hou, Yifan China 2704 2015/01
120. Rakhmanov, Aleksandr Russia 2704 2014/12
121. Shankland, Samuel L United States 2704 2019/08
122. Pantsulaia, Levan Georgia 2703 2017/08
123. Vovk, Yuri Ukraine 2702 2015/11
124. Berkes, Ferenc Hungary 2701 2015/09
125. Zhigalko, Sergei Belarus 2701 2016/01
126. Fridman, Daniel Germany 2700 2013/01
127. Jumabayev, Rinat Kazakhstan 2700 2016/04