# List of female chess players by peak FIDE rating with countries?

Tags: history, rating, fide, statistics, records

same question as [here](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34754/list-of-female-chess-players-by-peak-fide-rating) but with countries please. hopefully we can have a list as close to the original wiki page as possible.

I'll start:

1 - Hungary - Judit Polgar - 2735 - 2005-07 - 1976 - N/A - first and only female player so far to achieve 2700+ rating

Comment: There's now [a corresponding section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_players_by_peak_FIDE_rating#Highest-rated_female_players) in [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_players_by_peak_FIDE_rating), which is currently up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are the results from the relevant queries on my database constructed from the downloads available from the [FIDE rating download website](https://ratings.fide.com/download.phtml) for the top 100 (actually 102 since there was a 3 way tie for 100th place) female players by standard ratings.

The "Period" is the first FIDE rating list in which the player achieved the rating. If the player didn't play rated standard for a year after that then they obviously retain the rating for the next year so the "Period" is the year and month in which FIDE first recorded that rating for them.

**PlayerName    FedName MaxRating   Period**

1. Polgar, Judit Hungary 2735 2005/07
2. Hou, Yifan China 2686 2015/03
3. Koneru, Humpy India 2623 2009/07
4. Muzychuk, Anna Slovenia 2606 2012/07
5. Ju, Wenjun China 2604 2017/03
6. Goryachkina, Aleksandra Russia 2596 2021/06
7. Muzychuk, Anna Ukraine 2587 2012/10
8. Kosintseva, Tatiana Russia 2581 2010/11
9. Zhao, Xue China 2579 2013/09
10. Polgar, Zsuzsa Hungary 2577 2005/01
11. Kosintseva, Nadezhda Russia 2576 2010/11
12. Xie, Jun China 2574 2008/01
13. Dzagnidze, Nana Georgia 2573 2015/06
14. Muzychuk, Mariya Ukraine 2563 2016/03
15. Muzychuk, Mariya Ukraine 2563 2019/04
16. Kosteniuk, Alexandra Russia 2561 2018/01
17. Chiburdanidze, Maia USSR 2560 1988/01
18. Galliamova, Alisa Russia 2560 1998/07
19. Lahno, Kateryna Russia 2560 2018/12
20. Stefanova, Antoaneta Bulgaria 2560 2003/01
21. Lahno, Kateryna Ukraine 2557 2012/01
22. Chiburdanidze, Maia Georgia 2551 1999/01
23. Cramling, Pia Sweden 2550 2008/10
24. Gunina, Valentina Russia 2548 2015/06
25. Zhu, Chen Qatar 2548 2008/01
26. Lei, Tingjie China 2545 2018/03
27. Harika, Dronavalli India 2543 2016/11
28. Cmilyte, Viktorija Lithuania 2542 2017/06
29. Zhu, Chen China 2539 2000/07
30. Sebag, Marie France 2537 2013/03
31. Zatonskih, Anna United States 2537 2011/05
32. Khotenashvili, Bela Georgia 2531 2013/06
33. Tan, Zhongyi China 2530 2018/08
34. Batsiashvili, Nino Georgia 2528 2018/03
35. Danielian, Elina Armenia 2521 2011/07
36. Ioseliani, Nana Georgia 2520 1997/07
37. Saduakassova, Dinara Kazakhstan 2519 2020/01
38. Xu, Yuhua China 2517 2006/04
39. Paehtz, Elisabeth Germany 2513 2018/09
40. Wang, Lei China 2512 2001/10
41. Hoang, Thanh Trang Hungary 2511 2013/11
42. Pogonina, Natalija Russia 2508 2014/07
43. Kovalevskaya, Ekaterina Russia 2507 2001/07
44. Zhu, Jiner China 2507 2019/10
45. Arakhamia-Grant, Ketevan Scotland 2506 2009/07
46. Stefanova, Antoaneta FIDE 2506 2011/05
47. Wang, Pin China 2506 2000/10
48. Abdumalik, Zhansaya Kazakhstan 2505 2021/07
49. Girya, Olga Russia 2505 2017/09
50. Polgar, Sofia Hungary 2505 1998/07
51. Socko, Monika Poland 2505 2008/04
52. Mkrtchian, Lilit Armenia 2503 2010/01
53. Ruan, Lufei China 2503 2014/01
54. Krush, Irina United States 2502 2013/10
55. Matveeva, Svetlana Russia 2502 2004/01
56. Ushenina, Anna Ukraine 2502 2007/07
57. Qin, Kanying China 2501 2000/07
58. Skripchenko, Almira France 2501 2003/01
59. Javakhishvili, Lela Georgia 2500 2010/03
60. Zhukova, Natalia Ukraine 2499 2010/05
61. Skripchenko, Almira Moldova 2497 2001/10
62. Gaprindashvili, Nona USSR 2495 1987/07
63. Ioseliani, Nana USSR 2495 1988/07
64. Huang, Qian China 2494 2013/09
65. Kashlinskaya, Alina Russia 2494 2020/04
66. Khademalsharieh, Sarasadat Iran 2494 2020/01
67. Hoang, Thanh Trang Vietnam 2493 2000/10
68. Arakhamia-Grant, Ketevan Georgia 2490 1997/01
69. Nominerdene, Davaademberel Mongolia 2490 2016/04
70. Maric, Alisa Yugoslavia 2489 1999/07
71. Shuvalova, Polina Russia 2489 2021/06
72. Peptan, Corina-Isabela Romania 2485 2003/07
73. Vijayalakshmi, Subbaraman India 2485 2005/10
74. Dembo, Yelena Greece 2482 2009/09
75. Gaponenko, Inna Ukraine 2482 2005/04
76. Atalik, Ekaterina Turkey 2481 2011/09
77. Galliamova, Alisa Ukraine 2480 1996/01
78. Bodnaruk, Anastasia Russia 2479 2016/06
79. Shen, Yang China 2479 2016/09
80. Arakhamia-Grant, Ketevan USSR 2475 1991/07
81. Melia, Salome Georgia 2475 2014/08
82. Khurtsidze, Nino Georgia 2472 1999/07
83. Peng, Zhaoqin Netherlands 2472 2002/04
84. Moser, Eva Austria 2471 2012/07
85. Daulyte, Deimante Lithuania 2470 2018/07
86. Korbut, Ekaterina Russia 2467 2008/04
87. Munguntuul, Batkhuyag Mongolia 2467 2011/09
88. Romanko, Marina Russia 2466 2009/04
89. Kachiani-Gersinska, Ketino Germany 2465 2002/04
90. Rajlich, Iweta Poland 2465 2009/09
91. Hunt, Harriet V England 2463 2009/01
92. Alexandrova, Olga Ukraine 2462 2003/01
93. Guo, Qi China 2462 2014/03
94. Bojkovic, Natasa Yugoslavia 2460 1994/07
95. Mammadzada, Gunay Azerbaijan 2460 2021/07
96. Paikidze, Nazi Georgia 2455 2011/01
97. Tairova, Elena Russia 2455 2009/11
98. Padmini, Rout India 2454 2015/03
99. Bulmaga, Irina Romania 2453 2020/02
100. Ding, Yixin China 2451 2014/07
101. Khukhashvili, Sopiko Georgia 2451 2009/09
102. Stepovaia, Tatiana Russia 2451 2001/07

Comment: You have some duplicates in there (e.g. Anna Muzychuk on 4 and 7, Mariya Muzychuk on 14 and 15, Kateryna Lahno on 19 and 21).

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's just use the list from Brian Towers' answer on the other topic and add the relevant countries. **I didn't yet add all the countries.**

I make this a community wiki since I won't have time to check data for all players myself.

When a player has (or has had) several nationalities, we pick the flag she was playing for when reaching her highest rating.

1. Polgar, Judit 2735 7/2005, 10/2005 , Hungary
2. Hou, Yifan 2686 3/2015, 5/2015 , China
3. Koneru, Humpy 2623 7/2009 , India
4. Muzychuk, Anna 2606 7/2012, 8/2012 , Ukraine
5. Ju, Wenjun 2604 3/2017 , China
6. Goryachkina, Aleksandra 2593 2/2021 , Russia
7. Kosintseva, Tatiana 2581 11/2020 , Russia
8. Zhao, Xue 2579 9/2013, 10/2013 , China
9. Polgar, Zsuzsa 2577 1/2005 , Hungary
10. Kosintseva, Nadezhda 2576 11/2010 , Russia
11. Xie, Jun 2574 1/2008 , China
12. Dzagnidze, Nana 2573 6/2015 - 10/2015 , Georgia
13. Muzychuk, Mariya 2563 3/2016, 4-6/2019 , Ukraine
14. Kosteniuk, Alexandra 2561 1/2018, 2/2018 , Russia
15. Lahno, Kateryna 2560 12/2018 - 2/2019 , Ukraine
16. Galliamova, Alisa 2560 7/1998 , Georgia
17. Stefanova, Antoaneta 2560 1/2003, 5-7/2010 , Bulgaria
18. Chiburdanidze, Maia 2560 1/1988 , Georgia (USSR)
19. Cramling, Pia 2550 10/2008 , Sweden
20. Gunina, Valentina 2548 6-7/2015 , Ukraine
21. Zhu, Chen 2548 1/2008 , China
22. Lei, Tingjie 2545 3/2018 , China
23. Harika, Dronavalli 2543 11-12/2016
24. Cmilyte, Viktorija 2542 6/2017 , Latvia
25. Sebag, Marie 2537 3/2013 , France
26. Zatonskih, Anna 2537 5/2011 , USA
27. Khotenashvili, Bela 2531 6/2013
28. Tan, Zhongyi 2530 3-4/2016 , China
29. Batsiashvili, Nino 2528 3/2018
30. Danielian, Elina 2521 7/2011
31. Ioseliani, Nana 2520 7/1977 , Georgia (USSR)
32. Saduakassova, Dinara 2519 1/2020
33. Xu, Yuhua 2517 4/2006 - 7/2007 , China
34. Paehtz, Elisabeth 2513 9-10/2018 , Germany
35. Wang, Lei 2512 10/2001 , China
36. Hoang, Thanh Trang 2511 11/2013 - 2/2014
37. Pogonina, Natalija 2508 7/2014
38. Kovalevskaya, Ekaterina 2507 7/2001
39. Zhu, Jiner 2507 10/2019 , China
40. Arakhamia-Grant, Ketevan 2506 7/2009
41. Wang, Pin 2506 10/2000
42. Polgar, Sofia 2505 7/1998 , Hungary
43. Girya, Olga 2505 9/2017
44. Socko, Monika 2505 4/2008 , Poland
45. Ruan, Lufei 2503 1/2014
46. Mkrtchian, Lilit 2503 1-3/2010
47. Matveeva, Svetlana 2502 1/2004
48. Krush, Irina 2502 10-11/2013, USA
49. Ushenina, Anna 2502 7/2007
50. Qin, Kanying 2501 7/2000
51. Skripchenko, Almira 2501 1-4/2003 , France

Comment: Actually I didn't realise at 1st that all the countries weren't added since I actuallly didn't read too thoroughly. I just assumed all the countries were there because I assumed you followed the same thing Brian Towers did but got countries as well in the query/search/filter/whatchamacallit.