# List of female chess players by their peak FIDE blitz rating

Tags: history, rating, fide, statistics, records

Similar to these:

1. [List of female chess players by peak FIDE rating](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34754/list-of-female-chess-players-by-peak-fide-rating)
2. [List of female chess players by peak FIDE rating with countries?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36698/list-of-female-chess-players-by-peak-fide-rating-with-countries)
3. [List of chess players by their peak FIDE blitz rating](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36691/list-of-chess-players-by-their-peak-fide-blitz-rating)
4. [List of chess players by their peak FIDE rapid rating](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36700/list-of-chess-players-by-their-peak-fide-rapid-rating)
5. [List of female chess players by their peak FIDE rapid rating](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36701/list-of-female-chess-players-by-their-peak-fide-rapid-rating)

There is a [Wiki list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_players_by_peak_FIDE_rating#) is for all of the top-rated FIDE chess players. We now have a [list](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34754/list-of-female-chess-players-by-peak-fide-rating) for the top female chess players by peak FIDE rating. As in [link above](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36691/list-of-chess-players-by-their-peak-fide-blitz-rating), we have a list of top chess players peak FIDE blitz rating. But where is the list of top female chess players by peak FIDE blitz rating? Please include countries.

I'll start

1. Polgar, Judit Hungary 2736 2014/07
2. Hou, Yifan China 2704 2015/01 (Good for Hou Yifan in being rated 2700+ in blitz though not standard.)

Update: See answer: There are indeed no other females in [the list above](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36691/list-of-chess-players-by-their-peak-fide-blitz-rating).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the results from the relevant queries on my database constructed from the downloads available from the [FIDE rating download website](https://ratings.fide.com/download.phtml) for female players with blitz ratings of 2400 and over (chosen as the nearest round number to give close to 100 players). Since you also ask for countries I've included distinct player/country combinations.

The "Period" is the first FIDE rating list in which the player achieved the rating. If the player didn't play rated blitz for a year after that then they obviously retain the rating for the next year so the "Period" is the year and month in which FIDE first recorded that rating for them.

**PlayerName    FedName MaxRating   Period**

1. Polgar, Judit Hungary 2736 2014/07
2. Hou, Yifan China 2704 2015/01
3. Muzychuk, Anna Ukraine 2665 2014/05
4. Gunina, Valentina Russia 2652 2015/04
5. Lahno, Kateryna Russia 2643 2017/01
6. Muzychuk, Anna Slovenia 2639 2013/01
7. Kosteniuk, Alexandra Russia 2612 2013/03
8. Dzagnidze, Nana Georgia 2591 2014/05
9. Stefanova, Antoaneta Bulgaria 2590 2016/04
10. Kosintseva, Tatiana Russia 2578 2014/05
11. Zhao, Xue China 2576 2014/05
12. Paehtz, Elisabeth Germany 2574 2013/09
13. Harika, Dronavalli India 2573 2015/01
14. Ushenina, Anna Ukraine 2573 2014/01
15. Ju, Wenjun China 2571 2016/05
16. Tan, Zhongyi China 2565 2015/08
17. Koneru, Humpy India 2558 2013/01
18. Zhukova, Natalia Ukraine 2553 2012/07
19. Lahno, Kateryna Ukraine 2549 2014/01
20. Lei, Tingjie China 2543 2019/06
21. Stefanova, Antoaneta FIDE 2540 2017/01
22. Cmilyte, Viktorija Lithuania 2532 2013/01
23. Bodnaruk, Anastasia Russia 2530 2016/11
24. Kosintseva, Nadezhda Russia 2519 2012/07
25. Wang, Jue China 2512 2013/06
26. Sebag, Marie France 2504 2014/01
27. Chiburdanidze, Maia Georgia 2497 2012/07
28. Krush, Irina United States 2494 2016/12
29. Khotenashvili, Bela Georgia 2485 2014/01
30. Charochkina, Daria Russia 2481 2013/10
31. Ding, Yixin China 2476 2012/08
32. Kulon, Klaudia Poland 2473 2018/09
33. Huang, Qian China 2472 2014/07
34. Cori T., Deysi Peru 2470 2012/07
35. Socko, Monika Poland 2465 2017/02
36. Matnadze, Ana Spain 2464 2012/07
37. Khademalsharieh, Sarasadat Iran 2463 2019/06
38. Staniak, Maria Poland 2458 2018/07
39. Abdumalik, Zhansaya Kazakhstan 2457 2018/01
40. Munguntuul, Batkhuyag Mongolia 2455 2012/08
41. Batsiashvili, Nino Georgia 2454 2012/07
42. Romanko, Marina Russia 2454 2014/11
43. Melia, Salome Georgia 2453 2012/07
44. Zhu, Chen Qatar 2451 2013/01
45. Goryachkina, Aleksandra Russia 2449 2018/01
46. Arabidze, Meri Georgia 2445 2016/11
47. Pham, Le Thao Nguyen Vietnam 2444 2015/11
48. Muzychuk, Mariya Ukraine 2443 2012/07
49. Pogonina, Natalija Russia 2443 2015/06
50. Zatonskih, Anna United States 2442 2013/01
51. Javakhishvili, Lela Georgia 2439 2017/08
52. Rogule, Laura Latvia 2438 2016/07
53. Moser, Eva Austria 2436 2013/10
54. Cramling, Pia Sweden 2435 2018/01
55. Gvetadze, Sofio Georgia 2435 2013/05
56. Michna, Marta Germany 2433 2018/01
57. Danielian, Elina Armenia 2432 2012/07
58. Lomineishvili, Maia Georgia 2431 2012/07
59. Zhai, Mo China 2429 2012/08
60. Khurtsidze, Nino Georgia 2428 2012/07
61. Kovalevskaya, Ekaterina Russia 2427 2012/08
62. Kashlinskaya, Alina Russia 2426 2017/11
63. Mkrtchian, Lilit Armenia 2426 2012/07
64. Girya, Olga Russia 2425 2013/10
65. Guo, Qi China 2425 2013/06
66. Alexandrova, Olga Spain 2424 2014/08
67. Pustovoitova, Daria Russia 2423 2016/01
68. Hoang, Thanh Trang Hungary 2422 2016/11
69. Gaponenko, Inna Ukraine 2421 2017/11
70. Kalinina, Olga Ukraine 2421 2014/07
71. Galliamova, Alisa Russia 2417 2016/11
72. Peptan, Corina-Isabela Romania 2417 2013/01
73. Turova, Irina Russia 2416 2015/08
74. Khukhashvili, Sopiko Georgia 2415 2012/09
75. Skripchenko, Almira France 2412 2018/01
76. Houska, Jovanka England 2411 2014/05
77. Maltsevskaya, Aleksandra Russia 2411 2020/10
78. L'Ami, Alina Romania 2409 2014/01
79. Li, Ruofan Singapore 2406 2015/05
80. Sukandar, Irine Kharisma Indonesia 2406 2016/01
81. Vaishali R India 2405 2017/11
82. Szczepkowska-Horowska, Karina Poland 2404 2013/01
83. Tania, Sachdev India 2404 2012/07
84. Arakhamia-Grant, Ketevan Scotland 2403 2013/07
85. Padmini, Rout India 2403 2018/09
86. Paikidze, Nazi Georgia 2402 2012/07
87. Buksa, Nataliya Ukraine 2401 2018/04
88. Vasilevich, Tatjana Ukraine 2400 2014/08