# List of records for youngest superGMs since 1950? (or 1970 or whenever FIDE started rating people. or basically after 2700s after Fischer)

Tags: history, statistics, records, titles, super-grandmaster

On Wiki, we have the [List of youngest grandmasters since 1950](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_prodigy#List_of_youngest_grandmasters). What about superGMs (defined anyone who has [reached 2700+ peak FIDE standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_players_by_peak_FIDE_rating)) instead of GMs: where can I find a list for the youngest to pass 2700+?

**Notes**:

1. [The above link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_players_by_peak_FIDE_rating) obviously doesn't answer the question directly, but I guess the members of my required list are a subset of the list of everyone who's gotten 2700+ peak standard FIDE rating.
2. I guess the list begins with Bobby Fischer ('first player to achieve 2700+ rating') and ends with Wei Yi ('Youngest player to reach a rating over 2700').

**So I guess the list is gonna look like...**

1. Bobby Fischer - (insert rating obtained for 1st time over 2700) - (insert month and year when this rating was obtained) - (insert age for when this rating was obtained)
2. ?
3. ?
4. Wei Yi - (insert rating obtained for 1st time over 2700) - (insert month and year when this rating was obtained) - (insert age for when this rating was obtained)

---

**Bonus**: youngest female superGMs

1. Judit Polgar
2. N/A

Comment: Judit Polgar became also the first woman GM, at 15 yers old, younger than Bobby. I didn't know that, thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Universal_learner judit polgar was the 1st woman SGM not 1st woman GM

Comment: I haven't downvoted any of these, but I do think the constant stream of "List of youngest <x>" questions is of dubious utility.

Comment: @Cleveland what about my lists of players by their peak ratings?

Comment: @Cleveland why? is there something wrong with asking about trivia?

Comment: @BCLC there is the feeling that they could be mostly answered just by downloading the data (https://ratings.fide.com/download.phtml). I know you will now say 'okay then download the data and analyse it for my answers!' but SE is not _really_ about sourcing hard work one is unwilling to put in but rather expertise one simply doesn't have. You can do everyone a favour by writing an article containing all your 'youngest' world record progression findings rather than bombarding SE with every possible permutation (most of which no-one helps with in any substantial way, as far as I can tell...)

Comment: As for the proliferation of several questions, although there is no guidance on SE regarding similar but slightly distinct questions, there should be, especially when it comes to those that a single methodology neatly addresses and which vary in only a single variable (e.g. title or FIDE rating). For example, I would ask 'who was the highest ever rated player at ages 60-90' in *one* thread rather than make 31 threads '...age 60?', '...age 61?', ..., '...age 90?'

Comment: @MobeusZoom 1 - ok so what do i look for there: subtract date of birth from date obtained and then sort column? 2 - what about [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36691/list-of-chess-players-by-their-peak-fide-blitz-rating?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [that question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36700/list-of-chess-players-by-their-peak-fide-rapid-rating?rq=1) ?

Comment: @MobeusZoom does the data there really include the dates they obtained 2700+ or IM or WIM or whatever as well as their dates of birth?

Comment: @Cleveland why does wiki even have a list of youngest grandmasters anyway?

Comment: @BCLC So *these* are the questions to be asking. Asking 'please list the youngest WIMs' sounds like you've given up on any viable data source and instead think any such list has to be assembled as a matter of trivia. Instead ask what you just asked me. 1 SE question should be enough to establish the methodology for using the data I linked to find the youngest to a given rating, or sort players by highest ever rating; another question to find out how to download data about when titles were awarded (surely FIDE has this information available; if necessary use the monthly title code 'g','wf',..)

Comment: The work to download the data would have to be done by anyone to answer the question and, excepting possibly asking about efficient ways to do it, you cannot expect anyone else to do that work when you wouldn't. (And why shouldn't you - after putting in this much effort to find trivia!)

Comment: The point I'm making is not that the question is easy but that a single methodology can answer all of them and it is that methodology (and/or necessary data sources) you should be asking for help with. (All these other threads should be tagged as duplicates there)

Comment: @MobeusZoom wait what is your opinion of [Beginner question gets 29 upvotes](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/949/beginner-question-gets-29-upvotes) ? and of [Should questions feature computer analysis whenever relevant?](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/950/should-questions-feature-computer-analysis-whenever-relevant)?

Comment: @MobeusZoom compromise/negotiate: can i just ask a new question about the methodology and the answer all those other questions myself and have those questions not tagged as duplicates?

Comment: @MobeusZoom what is your opinion of my lists of players by their peak ratings? eg [List of female chess players by their peak FIDE rapid rating](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36701/list-of-female-chess-players-by-their-peak-fide-rapid-rating)

Comment: @MobeusZoom From [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/po1a08/list_of_records_for_youngest_supergms_since_1950/hctahkh?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)

Comment: @MobeusZoom Update: [Ok fine, how do I answer questions like records for youngest to obtain a certain title?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36988/ok-fine-how-do-i-answer-questions-like-records-for-youngest-to-obtain-a-certain)

Comment: @MobeusZoom 'The work to download the data would have to be done by anyone to answer the question and, excepting possibly asking about efficient ways to do it, you cannot expect anyone else to do that work when you wouldn't.' --> i didn't have any problem with the questions about the peak ratings actually

Comment: @MobeusZoom in the new question i asked based on your suggestion, i got 6 downvotes in 4 hours. that's gotta be a record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/chess/comments/po1a08/list_of_records_for_youngest_supergms_since_1950/hctahkh?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3):

1. Fischer (28y 3m 23d) 1971 Jul (World #1)
2. Karpov (22y 11m 9d) 1974 May (World #2)
3. Kasparov (20y 8m 19d) 1984 Jan (World #1)
4. Shirov (19y 0m 3d) 1992 Jul (World #4)
5. Kramnik (18y 0m 6d) 1993 Jul (World #4)
6. Carlsen (16y 7m 1d) 2007 Jul (World #17) --> appears to be the biggest gap so far
7. Wei Yi (15y 8m 29d) 2015 Mar (World #44)

Answer (score 1):

My research tells me, that FIDE has only started rating players from 1970/71 on.[[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_players_by_peak_FIDE_rating)]

###### Background Knowledge

There are multiple databases listing players, for example [*OlympBase*](http://www.olimpbase.org/index.php), which contains the ratings of all (?) FIDE-registered players from 1971-2001, after which year, one can consult the current FIDE-list (which doesn't store ratings before then, apparently).
Before Fischer's time, I have found four players above an Elo of 2700[[3](https://2700chess.com/historical-masters)]¹: José Capablanca, Michail Botvinnik (GM with 39), Emanuel Lasker, Michail Tal (GM with 29). But these rating numbers are somewhat problematic, since before 1970, only *historic elo numbers* are availible for us; remember, FIDE only started using Elo in the early 70s, the german Wikipedia tells me, that Aljechin, for example, had a peak (historical!) Elo of **2860**, in May of 1931, which is higher than Kasparov's highest ever Elo of **2851**.
There is a website, called [2700chess](https://2700chess.com/records), which lists all players above a rating of 2700, but again, only from 1970/71 onwards, starting with Fischer.
Consider this a little background knowledge.

###### Serious lists?

I doubt, that there is any official list or database, listing grandmasters specifically since 1950 sorted sorted by youngest age.
The closest I have come to such list is a Youtube video by the very popular chess-website [chess.com](https://chess.com), with some sources in it's video description. Here you go: [Youtube video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EzP-S8jcDqo)

¹ I would like to point out, that Tsar Nicholas II. awarded the then informal title "Grandmaster" to the five best players in the 1914 Chess Tournament in St. Petersburg. That would make Capablanca GM with 26 years, Lasker with 46 years and Aljechin with 22 years of age.

I'm not too familiar with the mechanisms, with which others can modify my answer, but if someone find something of interest, he or she should go ahead, and edit my answer (if possible).

Comment: ah you mean the list for Elo 1950 onwards is possibly different from the list for FIDE 1970 onwards?

Comment: Yes, precisely. From before 1970, we only have historical elos.

Comment: 'there is any official list or database, listing grandmasters specifically since 1950 sorted sorted by youngest age' --> wait what do you mean? this list is precisely the very 1st thing i link. it's the same as the list in the youtube video. but i guess you meant to say supergms instead of gms?

Comment: You're very correct, thanks for pointing it out. I mean super GMs, yes!

Comment: FYI: see the answer i posted