# List of female chess players by their peak FIDE rapid rating

Tags: history, rating, fide, statistics, records

Similar to these questions:

1. [List of female chess players by peak FIDE rating](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34754/list-of-female-chess-players-by-peak-fide-rating)
2. [List of female chess players by peak FIDE rating with countries?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36698/list-of-female-chess-players-by-peak-fide-rating-with-countries)
3. [List of chess players by their peak FIDE blitz rating](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36691/list-of-chess-players-by-their-peak-fide-blitz-rating)
4. [List of female chess players by their peak FIDE blitz rating](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36699/list-of-female-chess-players-by-their-peak-fide-blitz-rating)
5. [List of chess players by their peak FIDE rapid rating](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36700/list-of-chess-players-by-their-peak-fide-rapid-rating)

There is a [Wiki list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chess_players_by_peak_FIDE_rating#) is for all of the top-rated FIDE chess players. We now have a [list](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34754/list-of-female-chess-players-by-peak-fide-rating) for the top female chess players by peak FIDE rating. As in link above, we have a [list](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/36700/list-of-chess-players-by-their-peak-fide-rapid-rating) of top chess players peak FIDE rapid rating. But where is the list of top female chess players by peak FIDE rapid rating? Please include countries.

Note: Usually I'd start with Judit Polgar (and then afterwards Hou Yifan) but in this case there's no Judit Polgar in the above rapid list for 2700+, so I wouldn't know how to start with them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the results from the relevant queries on my database constructed from the downloads available from the [FIDE rating download website](https://ratings.fide.com/download.phtml) for the top female players by rapid rating rated over 2450 (round number to give about 50 players - actually 53 players).

The "Period" is the first FIDE rating list in which the player achieved the rating. If the player didn't play rated standard for a year after that then they obviously retain the rating for the next year so the "Period" is the year and month in which FIDE first recorded that rating for them.

PlayerName  FedName MaxRating   Period

1. Polgar, Judit Hungary 2669 2013/08
2. Hou, Yifan China 2645 2016/09
3. Koneru, Humpy India 2626 2013/01
4. Ju, Wenjun China 2618 2019/01
5. Lahno, Kateryna Ukraine 2616 2013/01
6. Kosteniuk, Alexandra Russia 2612 2017/10
7. Muzychuk, Anna Ukraine 2611 2017/01
8. Lahno, Kateryna Russia 2599 2014/05
9. Gunina, Valentina Russia 2597 2014/01
10. Stefanova, Antoaneta Bulgaria 2582 2013/01
11. Dzagnidze, Nana Georgia 2580 2014/01
12. Muzychuk, Anna Slovenia 2577 2012/07
13. Cramling, Pia Sweden 2546 2012/07
14. Lei, Tingjie China 2545 2018/12
15. Zhao, Xue China 2545 2012/07
16. Stefanova, Antoaneta FIDE 2536 2017/04
17. Kosintseva, Tatiana Russia 2530 2014/05
18. Harika, Dronavalli India 2529 2012/07
19. Paehtz, Elisabeth Germany 2524 2014/01
20. Muzychuk, Mariya Ukraine 2521 2018/01
21. Kosintseva, Nadezhda Russia 2516 2013/01
22. Ushenina, Anna Ukraine 2513 2015/01
23. Tan, Zhongyi China 2509 2016/04
24. Goryachkina, Aleksandra Russia 2504 2019/01
25. Sebag, Marie France 2504 2013/01
26. Zatonskih, Anna United States 2504 2012/07
27. Pogonina, Natalija Russia 2501 2019/07
28. Javakhishvili, Lela Georgia 2499 2014/07
29. Arabidze, Meri Georgia 2497 2015/05
30. Girya, Olga Russia 2497 2020/01
31. Khotenashvili, Bela Georgia 2494 2018/05
32. Khurtsidze, Nino Georgia 2494 2012/11
33. Abdumalik, Zhansaya Kazakhstan 2490 2019/01
34. Krush, Irina United States 2490 2014/09
35. Socko, Monika Poland 2490 2015/04
36. Zhu, Chen Qatar 2489 2012/07
37. Danielian, Elina Armenia 2488 2018/01
38. Bodnaruk, Anastasia Russia 2487 2016/09
39. Galliamova, Alisa Russia 2485 2013/01
40. Chiburdanidze, Maia Georgia 2475 2012/07
41. Moser, Eva Austria 2469 2014/12
42. Batsiashvili, Nino Georgia 2467 2012/07
43. Huang, Qian China 2464 2018/07
44. Mkrtchian, Lilit Armenia 2464 2015/01
45. Cmilyte, Viktorija Lithuania 2462 2012/07
46. Pustovoitova, Daria Russia 2462 2017/01
47. Khademalsharieh, Sarasadat Iran 2460 2019/01
48. Matnadze, Ana Spain 2459 2014/09
49. Pham, Le Thao Nguyen Vietnam 2456 2018/01
50. Turova, Irina Russia 2456 2017/09
51. Munguntuul, Batkhuyag Mongolia 2455 2016/05
52. Skripchenko, Almira France 2452 2017/11
53. Guo, Qi China 2451 2017/10